People Present Business Ideas and Try to Get Sponsorship
I saw this show a couple of years ago on YouTube (so this wasn't on the actual station, so I don't remember who aired it), but it looked pretty modern and the people presenting ideas were using modern ideas and thinking ahead to the future, so this is probably late 2000s, early 2010s.
The particular episode I watched on YouTube was this guy proposing a plan to insert Bluetooth devices into people's brains, but the idea was immediately rejected by the hosts of the show because it was too "revolutionary".
I would like the name of the TV show, not the particular episode.

... and it's not "Shark Tank"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shark_Tank

or Dragon's Den?

@Catija looks like it was the first episode of Shark Tank!

Apparently, you watched the first episode of Shark Tank.
This show is famous for having their five "Sharks" (wealthy investors) consider 4-5 products or services to invest in. Some of these are very reasonable things and sometimes they're a bit... outlandish.

Shark Tank is an American reality television series that premiered August 9, 2009, on ABC. The show is a franchise of the international format Dragons' Den, which originated in Japan in 2001. Shark Tank shows aspiring entrepreneur-contestants make business presentations to a panel of "shark" investors, who then choose whether or not to invest.

The first episode contains the following:

"Mr. Tod's Pie Factory" a pie company (YES); "Ionic Ear" an implantable Bluetooth device requiring surgery to insert the device into the user's head (NO); "Wispots" an electronic hand-held device for waiting rooms (NO); "Ava the Elephant" (Emmy the Elephant during show, trademarked as Ava after) a plastic elephant shaped device that helps parents give small children oral medicine (YES); "College Foxes Packing Boxes" a spinoff professional packing and organizing service based on an already successful junk removal and moving business called College Hunks Hauling Junk[10] (NO).

I believe the "Ionic Ear" is the Bluetooth implant you're referring to.
